# PostInstall: Check if version is less than

Tags: postinstall

Is it possible to check if the previous version is: **"Less than"** a certain value using the `context.previousVersion()` field.

The documentation does a one-to-one comparison for a specific version like so:

```
if(context.previousVersion().compareTo(new Version(1,0)) == 0)
```

So could I check for *versions less than 1.0*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure about the PostInstall context, but looking at the documentation for [Version.compareTo()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_version.htm) I'd say it was possible.

Try something like:

```
if(context.previousVersion().compareTo(new Version(1,0)) < 0) {
    // Previous Version is Less than Version 1.0 code
}
```

---

Updated [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_version.htm#apex_System_Version_compareTo):

> **Return Value**
> Type: Integer
> Returns one of the following values:
>
> - zero if the current package version is equal to the specified package version
> - an Integer value greater than zero if the current package version is greater than the specified package version
> - an Integer value less than zero if the current package version is less than the specified package version

Comment: Your right, it's not documented, but actually that method returns a number *-1* if the version is less than the version given, and a *1* if it's greater.

Comment: Late to the party, but I wanted to comment to link to the documentation, that now includes the correct return values of compareTo() : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_version.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can also use **major()** and **minor()** methods in the Version object to get each part of the version number:

> *The version number has the format majorNumber.minorNumber.patchNumber (for example, 1.2.0)*

```
if ((context.previousVersion().major() == 1) 
     && (context.previousVersion().minor() > 0)
     && (System.requestVersion().minor() <=9))
{
    // Do something for versions  between 1.1 and 1.9
}
else if (context.previousVersion().compareTo(new Version(2,0)) >= 0)
{
    // Do something completely different for versions 2.0 or greater
}
```

[Source: Salesforce Version Class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_version.htm#apex_methods_system_version)